# Does Gtk.Popover need to be smaller than the parent window?

Tags: gtk

I tried using a Gtk.Popover inside my app

```
popover = new Gtk.Popover (this);
popover.width_request = 310;
popover.add (cities_search);
```

But this is how the popover is displayed:

[image]

While inspecting it using the Gtk inspector, this is how it looks:

[image]

If the popover cannot be bigger than the window, are there any alternative ways to use it??

Comment: In the Inspector screenshot it looks like your search bar isn't visible. Did you forget to call `show()` or `show_all()`? In GTK 3, widgets are not visible by default, you have to explicitly show them. (This was changed in GTK 4.)

Comment: Thanks, I had to use `show ()`. Now it appears.

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/543, this is what I found when I had googled it. So I thought, it was because the popover was bigger than the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James Westman's comment says, I had to use `show ()` to make it visible.

```
popover = new Gtk.Popover (this);
popover.width_request = 310;
popover.add (cities_search);

cities_search.show ();
```